# Intercept rdtsc instruction from guest vm userspace in KVM

Tags: intel, kvm, hypervisor, tsc, rdtsc

I'm stuck in the problem as the title says.I want to do this in VMM by adding

the *CPU_BASED_RDTSC_EXITING* flag in vmx.c(arch/x86/kvm) in *setup_vmcs_config* function,and

then handle the vm_exit by myself(ref this:[mail list](https://www.mail-archive.com/kvm@vger.kernel.org/msg23659.html)).The question is that I cannot

tell whether the vm_exit of rdtsc is caused by the guest kernel or the guest vm user

space application, the latter one is what exactly I want to intercept.I have tried to search

through qemu-kvm-1.2.0 src to find other ways to intercept the rdtsc instruction,I find

rdtsc clue in target-i386/translate.c.And I add a printf there, but I got nothing.So I

wonder if anyone could give me some little guidance to break through.Thank you a lot~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experiment,I almost find the answer to my own question.See the code below:

```
static int handle_rdtsc(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu)
{
    u64 data;
    if (vmx_get_msr(vcpu, MSR_IA32_TSC, &data)) {
    kvm_inject_gp(vcpu, 0);
    printk("wsh_handle_rdtsc_return\n");
    return 1;
  }

  vcpu->run->exit_reason = 20;
  vcpu->arch.regs[VCPU_REGS_RAX] = data & -1u;
  vcpu->arch.regs[VCPU_REGS_RDX] = (data >> 32) & -1u;
  skip_emulated_instruction(vcpu);
  if(vmx_get_cpl(vcpu)>0)
  {
      printk("wsh_handle_rdtsc,cpl:%d\n",vmx_get_cpl(vcpu));
  }
  return 1;
}
```

As you have seen above,I use vmx_get_cpl  to filter those rdtsc vm_exit caused by the guest kernel,and I fact,the printk always print 3,because the privellege level of guest vm applications is always 3.Any corrections is welcomed!

Comment: Very nice- did it work? were you trying to debug the latency of rdtsc? I ask as I'm doing the same